# Migrate Lego Boost Android app data to another device

Tags: programming, software, boost

I have a Lego Boost Android application installed on device #1 and the app is logged into my LEGO cloud account (the same used for Lego Life etc. too) and is fully synced with cloud. On this device I made some progress, built about half of the models in the app and hence some models are "unlocked" while others are not yet. There is certain progress I made in comparison to clean Boost app install.

Now, is it possible to "migrate" the progress I made in Boost app on device #1 to another Android device (say device #2)? I tried to log in with the same Lego credentials on device #2 but my progress has not downloaded from the cloud even as device #1 is fully synced. Am I missing something or is it simply not possible to transfer the data of Boost app between devices? Has anyone tried to do this?

PS. Neither of my devices is rooted.